# Loop within a loop (Again) for template

Tags: loop

I know that the question was already asked but all the answer i found doesnt help me..

I made an HTML page that I would like to integrate in Wordpress.

The integration of the theme was done properly until I get to the posts part

I have a problem with algorithms to display posts so I know it comes from the Wordpress loop.

I have done several searches on Wordpress loops but I do not understand the different uses.

Here is the HTML code base that I would like to loop :

```
<div class="oeuvres">
   <div class="line0"><!-- should be dynamic -->
    <div class="oeuvre">
        <img class="img-oeuvre" src="ressources/creations/lisemassages.png" alt="">
        <div class="infos-oeuvre">
           <p>Title</p>
           <p>Content</p>
           <a class="btn-oeuvre" href="" target="_blank">Voir le site</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="oeuvre">
        <img class="img-oeuvre" src="ressources/creations/centredesoi.png" alt="">
        <div class="infos-oeuvre">
            <p>Title</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <a class="btn-oeuvre" href="" target="_blank">voir le site</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div><!--class line0 -->
</div>

<div class="oeuvres">
   <div class="line1"><!--Should be dynamic-->
    <div class="oeuvre">
        <div class="infos-oeuvre">
                <p>title</p>
                <p>Content</p>
                <a class="btn-oeuvre" href="" target="_blank">Voir le site</a>
        </div>
        <img class="img-oeuvre" src="ressources/creations/comparepc.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="oeuvre">
        <div class="infos-oeuvre">
            <p>Title</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <a class="btn-oeuvre" href="" target="_blank">voir nos créations</a>
        </div>
        <img class="img-oeuvre" src="ressources/creations/wine&amp;sound.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
   </div><!--class line1 -->
</div>
```

Here's the code i've already done but i got some problem : there's only 3 articles which are repeated :

```
<?php   
     //Variables needed for the template
     $req = new WP_Query('category_name=creations') ;    //object with the posts
     $cptPosts = $req->post_count ; //nomber of post
     $cptOeuvres = $cptPosts/2 ; //number of div .Oeuvres needed
     $iOeuvres = 1 ; //counter of div.oeuvres
     $iPost = 1 ; //counter of posts
    ?>

    <?php echo 'cptpost = '.$cptPosts ; echo 'cptoeuvres = '.$cptOeuvres ;// to check $cptPost/$cptoeuvres value ?>

    <?php if ($req->have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while($iOeuvres <= $cptOeuvres): ?>
            <?php //if $iOeuvres is pair use .line1 else .line2 ?>               
            <?php if($iOeuvres%2 == 0) : ?>

                 <div class = "oeuvres">
                   <div class ="line1">

            <?php else : ?>

                 <div class = "oeuvres">            
                    <div class ="line0">

            <?php endif ;?>


            <?php while($req->have_posts()) : $req->the_post() ; ?>

                <?php //show only 2 posts per line?>                          
                <?php if($iPost<=2):?>

                     <?php //if iOeuvres is pair, image goes before ?>
                     <?php if($iOeuvres%2 == 0) : ?>   

                         <div class="oeuvre">
                            <img class="img-oeuvre" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/ressources/creations/lisemassages.png" alt="">
                            <div class="infos-oeuvre">
                                <p><?php the_title() ; ?></p>
                                <p><?php the_content() ; ?></p>                                
                                <a class="btn-oeuvre" href="http://lisemassages.fr" target="_blank">Voir le site</a>

                            </div><!--fermeture div.infos oeuvre-->
                          </div><!--fermeture div .oeuvre-->

                     <?php else : ?>

                           <div class="oeuvre">                                                
                              <div class="infos-oeuvre">
                                   <p><?php the_title() ; ?></p>
                                   <p><?php the_content() ; ?></p>
                                    <a class="btn-oeuvre" href="http://lisemassages.fr" target="_blank">Voir le site</a>
                               </div><!--fermeture div.infos oeuvre-->
                               <img class="img-oeuvre" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/ressources/creations/lisemassages.png" alt="">
                           </div><!--fermeture div .oeuvre--> 

                      <?php endif ; ?>

                      <?php $iPost++ ;?>

                  <?php else : ?>

                        <!-- $iPost > 2 : close the bracket -->
                        <!--of div.line and div oeuvreS -> add 1 div .oeuvreS -->          
                        </div><!--fermeture div .line0/1-->
                      </div><!--fermeture div .oeuvreS-->

                   <?php $iPost=1; endif ;?>

               <?php endwhile; ?>

               <?php $iOeuvres++ ; ?>                

          <?php endwhile ;  ?>

       <?php else : ?>
            <!-- no post-->
            <h1>Rien du tout</h1>
       <?php endif ;?>
```

I dont know if my code is understable ...my english either...

But my main question is how to keep the value in a innerloop when those are in an another loop .(best example in my mind is like counting room in a hotel : floor 1 : you begin with 1,2....5 and floor 2, you continue with 6,7,8...)

Any help would be great !

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]

If I understand correctly, what you call the "outer loop" is just for building a two-column layout. If so, you don't need to call two WordPress loops, just open a "fake" oeuvres at the beginning, close a "fake" oeuvres at the end, do a single loop (a single while have_posts()) and close and re-open an oeuvres DIV every 2 posts (when $iOeuvres%2 == 0).

Let me know if that makes sense.

[original answer]

**First problem:** If you do two loops, you should be using different names for the WP_Query  objects (for example, $req1 and $req2 instead of two $req). Otherwise, the inner one will override the values from the outer one.

**Second problem:** You are missing $req->the_post() on the outer query. That means posts will never advance.

But do you really need a WP Loop within a WP Loop? I don't see any request for posts for the inner query, you only do a single call for WP_Query() on line 3. Maybe if you clarify what you are trying to fetch (which post types, how they nest, etc.) I can help more.

Comment: I knew that my english would be a problem... Whatever ! the outer loop is just here to open/close the .oeuvreS and . line0/1 div. the inner loop serve to display the different element of the post (by using the_title function or the_content function) What im trying to do in short is to display 2 post per .oeuvres div.... I dont know if im more understable

Comment: i dont think that i need 2 WP query objet cause i just want to display 1 category... Or am i thinking wrong ?

Comment: (edited answer)

If I understand correctly, what you call the "outer loop" is just for building a two-column layout. If so, you don't need to call two WordPress loops, just open a "fake" oeuvres at the beginning, close a "fake" oeuvres at the end, do a single loop (a single while have_posts()) and close and re-open an oeuvres DIV every 2 posts (when $iOeuvres%2 == 0).

Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: ive tried your solution, but there was something going wrong when the number of posts is impair. !i figured out the right algorithm but maybe need some improvements

Answer (score 0):

here's the code which generate the right html. Maybe the code needs some improveme nts.

```
   <?php

      reqCrea = new WP_Query('category_name=creations'); //objet contenant les posts de la categorie creations
      $cptPosts = $reqCrea->post_count; //nombre de post

                ?>
                <?php
                //echo 'cptpost = ' . $cptPosts;                    
                if ($reqCrea->have_posts()) :
                    $i = 0;
                    $ligne = 0;
                    $sortie = false;
                    while ($reqCrea->have_posts()) :

                        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
                        $url = $thumb['0'];
                        echo '<div class="oeuvres">' ; 
                        // Sortie en cas de nb pairs de post
                        if ($i >= $cptPosts - 1 && ($cptPosts % 2 == 0))
                            break;

                        // Post de début de ligne
                        the_post();

                        $ligne = $ligne % 2;
                        ?>
                        <div class="line<?php echo $ligne; ?>">
                            <?php
                            do {
                                // Impair -> 2eme post sur une meme ligne
                                if (($i % 2) != 0) {
                                    the_post();
                                }
                                ?> 
                                <div class="oeuvre">
                                    <?php if ($ligne == 0): ?> 
                                        <img class="img-oeuvre" src="<?php echo $url ; ?>" alt="">
                                    <?php endif; ?> 
                                    <div class="infos-oeuvre">
                                        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                                        <a class="btn-oeuvre" href="http://lisemassages.fr" target="_blank">Voir le site</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php if ($ligne != 0): ?> 
                                        <img class="img-oeuvre" src="<?php echo $url ; ?>" alt="">
                                    <?php endif; ?> 
                                </div>

                                <?php
                                // Sortie en cas de nb impairs de post
                                if ($i >= $cptPosts - 1 && ($cptPosts % 2 != 0)) {
                                    $sortie = true;
                                    break;
                                }

                                if (($i % 2) == 0) {
                                    $i++;
                                } else {
                                    $i++;
                                    break;
                                }
                            } while ($reqCrea->have_posts());
                            if ($sortie)
                                break;

                            $ligne++;
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    endwhile;
                else :
                    ?>
                </div>
                <h1>Rien du tout</h1>
            <?php endif; ?>
```